# Am I having too much swap?

Tags: centos, partition, swap

Am I having too much swap space if my server is a 8GB physical ram and I would like to set my swap to 16GB. I am planning to use this server for shared hosting would like know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

Best practices say you should have *some* swap, but if you're using a lot of swap, it's highly likely that you have under-provisioned RAM on your system. I tend to never devote more than 2GB of swap to a system, regardless of the amount of physical RAM available.

Comment: The downside to this in the Windows world (yeah the question is linux based) is that a full memory dump isn't possible if you do this.

Comment: @TheCleaner The same is (generally) true in the Unix world as well -- crash dumps are written to swap if the system panics. Of course if you're having kernel panics you've probably got *bigger problems* than how big your swap partition is...